# Select merge in ecto 3.0

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am implementing select merge to build a query for aggregate functions. This is my code

```
Enum.reduce(opts_aggregate, queryable, fn {aggregate_type, fields}, 
  queryable ->
    case aggregate_type do
      "$max" ->
        case fields do
          fields when is_list(fields) ->
            Enum.reduce(fields, queryable, fn field, queryable ->
              build_max(queryable, field)
            end)

          field when is_binary(field) ->
            build_max(queryable, field)
        end

      "$min" ->
        case fields do
          fields when is_list(fields) ->
            Enum.reduce(fields, queryable, fn  field, queryable ->
              build_min(queryable, field)
            end)

          field when is_binary(field) ->
            build_min(queryable, field)
        end
 end)


def build_max(queryable, field) do
  field = Helper.string_to_atom(field)

from(q in queryable,
   select_merge:  %{"$aggregate": %{"$max": %{^field => max(field(q, ^field))}}}
)
end

def build_min(queryable, field) do
  field = Helper.string_to_atom(field)

  from(q in queryable,
    select_merge:  %{"$aggregate": %{"$min": %{^field =>min(field(q,^field))}}}
)
```

end

The params are :

```
   opts = %{
     "$aggregate" => %{    
       "$max" => "level",
       "$min" => "beds"
     }
  }
```

This is the query i get in return:

```
select: merge(merge(f, %{"$aggregate": %{"$max": %{^:level => max(f.level)}}}), %{"$aggregate": %{"$min": %{^:level => min(f.beds)}}})>
```

I am getting `level` key in both queries.

```
  %{"$max": %{^:level => max(f.level)
   %{"$min": %{^:level => min(f.beds)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or this is ecto issue?

Is it possible instead of multiple nested merges inside the query I just get query like this:

```
select: merge(f, %{"$aggregate": %{"$max": %{^:level => max(f.level)}}}), %{"$aggregate": %{"$min": %{^:level => min(f.beds)}}})>
```

Thanks

Comment: Because field is dynamic. There could be any value in the field so its not hard coded

Comment: Oh, indeed, sorry. Try to give them different names then, like `field_min` and `field_max`. Looks like `Ecto` is confused by the same names since pinned fields are expanded at once.